# When to use a connection pool to MySQL in python?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, connection-pooling

I have a service that runs and executes at most 5-8 threads at the same time. The main thread creates a connection pool and allows the subsequent threads it spawns to get a connection from this.

Should I bother with a pool in this use case or stick to a single connection that I then pass to each thread?

Comment: can you clarify if the threads need concurrent access?  Are they sharing session data?  MySQL doesn't care if you use a pool or not.  If you open/close connections frequently, you may have performance issues - which pooling helps with.

Comment: Yes the threads will be performing SQL at the same time, whether it is exactly the same time is up to chance.

Comment: Connection method could have a great impact, if it's TCP/IP then a pool would help for sure. For socket connections the pool would help to have stats and connections maintenance but not much with performance.